# Why JavaScript can't find given InnerHTML and returns Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Why site http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/test/ throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`?

**HTML** (http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/test/):

```
<div class="castle_array" id="2x1" name="2x1"></div>
<div class="castle_array" id="3x1" name="3x1"></div>
<div class="castle_array" id="4x1" name="4x1"></div>
...
```

**JavaScript** (http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/test/B_modeWindow.js):

```
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
for (y = 1; y <= 5; y++) {
  document.getElementById(x+"x"+y).addEventListener("click",B_modeWindow('1',this.id));
}}
```

When I alter

`("click",B_modeWindow('1',this.id)`

to

`("click",B_modeWindow('1','string')`

it works like a charm - why?

Comment: Because the JavaScript isn't finding the element on which it should, apparently, be working. Please post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the, or your, problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental issues with your code.

First, when you do `addEventListener("click", B_modeWindow('1', this.id));`, you're ***not*** assigning the `B_modewindow` callback to the click event handler, you are actually ***executing*** the function.

Secondly, in that context `this` **does not** refer to the clicked element, it refers to the **`Window`** object, thus `this.id` gives you `undefined`, use `event.target.id` instead:

To fix it, use the following instead:

```
var el = document.getElementById(x+"x"+y);
el.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  B_modeWindow('1', event.target.id);
});
```

Here's a simplified **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcsC3/)**.

Comment: Yet it thorws (not critical) error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null B_modeWindow.js:14
B_modeWindow.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`

Comment: @user1656447: Have you updated your code with mine? See my demo, the alerted value is correct. Can you update your site, so that I can check what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry Joao Silva, your solution works perfect. Thank you for very detailed and helpful explanation.